# Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints Custom Header Section

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I have a .nib for my custom header section for a table view:

[image]

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    let nib = UINib(nibName: "BillTableSection", bundle: nil)
    billTableView.register(nib, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "BillTableSection")

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    return 44.0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let cell = billTableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: "BillTableSection")

    return cell
}
```

The custom header section works, but whenever I insert a new section, A warning shows up on my console:

```
2017-10-02 14:56:32.791529+0800 Project[1017:14993] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x61000009f8b0 UIButton:0x7ff359d0d4a0.width == 22   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x61000009f900 UITextField:0x7ff359d19660.width == UILabel:0x7ff359d17650'$0.00'.width   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x61000009fa90 UITextField:0x7ff359d19660.leading == UIView:0x7ff359d010a0.leadingMargin   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x61000009ed20 H:[UITextField:0x7ff359d19660]-(30)-[UILabel:0x7ff359d17650'$0.00']   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x61000009f2c0 UIButton:0x7ff359d0d4a0.trailing == UIView:0x7ff359d010a0.trailingMargin   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x61000009ee60 H:[UILabel:0x7ff359d17650'$0.00']-(7)-[UIButton:0x7ff359d0d4a0]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x61000009f5e0 H:[UIView:0x7ff359d010a0]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':Project.BillTableSection:0x7ff359d0fc70 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x61000009f9a0 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7ff359d010a0]   (active, names: '|':Project.BillTableSection:0x7ff359d0fc70 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x61000009ff40 '_UITemporaryLayoutWidth' Project.BillTableSection:0x7ff359d0fc70.width == 0   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x61000009f8b0 UIButton:0x7ff359d0d4a0.width == 22   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

I tried to find the constraints that are not needed and remove them, but the layout I defined will not work on other devices anymore. Is it safe to ignore this warning? I'm not sure how to debug this... Please help!

Comment: Try setting the `priority` of button add item width constraint to 999 and see if still shows the warning.

Comment: @Amit I just set it to 999. Unfortunately the warning still shows...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should lower the `BtnAdd.trailing` priority to less than 1000. it looks like autolayout adds a temporary constraint

> `"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x61000009ff40 '_UITemporaryLayoutWidth' Project.BillTableSection:0x7ff359d0fc70.width == 0   (active)>"`

that squishes all the content, so removing that absolute priority will let your content adjust without conflicts.

---

Also, why is `TxtName.width` == `LblPrice.width`? Can't you adjust content hugging priority?

Comment: Thanks! It worked... I wanted to do a textfield that auto resizes the width when you edit, but also leaving some space in the middle to be able to end editing when tapped around but I'm not sure how to set it up properly.

Comment: That is actually clever… I thought you wanted to make the label fill the remaining width. Also people generally don't know how to use hugging priority and compression resistance, but your solution sounds good.